# Contesting closure of question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

**Final Edit:** After further exploring SE, I believe the correct action would have been to migrate the question to programmers.SE. I don't know how to do that, so I've asked the question there. Just doing my best to meet the community's requirements and expectations!

This question was closed as "...not a good fit..." [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416327/is-lamp-still-a-hot-web-development-scheme)

I have rephrased the question to discourage mere opinions. That said, I am seeking expert opinion on a topic I am not familiar with... perhaps there's room for a whole new wing of SE: "Get an Expert's Opinion."  ;)

Comment: It's subjective because it's a question of opinion.

Comment: Has anybody actually reviewed the rephrased question?  =)  I know this is a learning process, but the drive-by vote-downs are extreme "tough-love."

Comment: Downvotes on Meta don't necessarily have the same meaning as they do on other SE sites.

Comment: Just for reference, the way you request a migration is to flag the question for moderator attention.  That's best if you have some answers/context you want to preserve.  If it's just an "oops, I put it on the wrong site" and you haven't got anything you want to save, you can just delete the question and re-ask it on the appropriate site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a very subjective question.  It doesn't pass for the reasons specified in the close description:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve **facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.**

Whether or not something is a "hot" development scheme is not fact-based.

What stack you should use (if not LAMP) is not fact-based, and would solicit opinions and debate.

With that said, *this question may still be salvageable* if you have a specific problem with LAMP that you think needs addressing.

Comment: +1 The real question is "Should I stick with Linux Apache MySql PHP, or is there another schema I should focus on learning" which is highly subjective.

Comment: The question has been rephrased. It should meet the criteria now.